# primeng 4.3 to 9.0 datatable no longer exists

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm porting an angular 4 app to 9 and am also having to upgrade some of our third party controls.

In 4.3 of PrimeNg we made use of the DataTable in the following way:

```
import { DataTable, FilterMetadata, LazyLoadEvent } from 'primeng/primeng';


export abstract class GridFiltersBase {
    @ViewChild('modal') submittingModal: ActionSubmissionModal;
    @ViewChild(DataTable) public dataTable: DataTable;......

 if (this.dataTable) {
                this.dataTable.filterConstraints['date'] = this.dateMatch;
......
```

In Version 9, the closest reference I can find to this is :

```
import { FilterMetadata, LazyLoadEvent } from 'primeng/primeng';

import { TableModule } from 'primeng/table';
```

but there doesn't seem to be any methods on TableModule. The official documentation doesn't come up with anything when I search for TableModule. Has anyone managed to successfully upgrade primeNg who could steer me in the right direction?

if I change my import to be :

```
import { Table } from 'primeng/table';
```

then I obtain methods on my table, but not **filterConstraints**. this seems to have gone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the new FilterUtils.

```
this.dataTable.filterConstraints['date']
```

Should be:

```
FilterUtils['date']
```